# How I specify the Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath fields at Orion that set the name of MySQL database and table in Cygnus?

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

So far I have configured ContextBroker to send data to Cygnus which in turn saves data by default names in database.

But what if I want to target a specific database with a specific table?

I know I have to set:

```
dbName=<fiware-service> 
tableName=<fiware-servicePath>_<entityId>_<entityType>
```

I dont know where that file is, and I know it isnt in /etc/sysconfig/contextBroker because that folder doesnt exist.

**EDIT1:** here is my updatecontext:

```
(curl localhost:1026/NGSI10/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: FiwareDatabase' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /AllSensors' -d @- ) <<EOF
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Television",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "TV2",
            "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "channel",
                "type": "integer",
                "value": "14"
            },
            {
                "name": "volume",
                "type": "float",
                "value": "9"
            }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
EOF
```

As I said the table does get automatically created but the database doesnt.

Comment: There is no place where dbName and tableName can be set, since those are values automatically inferred by Cygnus based on `fiware-service`, `fiware-servicePath`, `entityId` and `entityType` notified values. Thus, you need to know how to set those values at Orion, specially `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicePath` (fgalan is going to give you exact details about that).

Answer (score 1):

Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath are set at entity creation time using HTTP headers in the entity creation REST request. Please have a look to the following sections in the Orion User Manual:

- [Service](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Multi_service_tenancy)
- [Service path](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Entity_service_paths)

**UPDATE**: for example, in order to create an entity in service "servA" and service path "/path1" you could use the example shown in [the create entity section in the manual](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Publish/Subscribe_Broker_-_Orion_Context_Broker_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Entity_Creation) adding two additionals HTTP headers to the curl line:

```
(curl localhost:1026/v1/updateContext -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Fiware-Service: servA' --header 'Fiware-ServicePath: /path1' -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
...
```

That would make to insert information in the following MySQL database/table (assuming that Cygnus is well configured, subscriptions are correct, etc.):

```
dbName=servA
tableName=path1_<entityId>_<entityType>
```

Note that the default behaviour is to store the information for each entity in a different table. That default behaviour can be changed, but if you are interested in that possibility, please create a new question in StackOverflow for dealing with that.

Comment: I read that and I still dont understand what exactly do I have to do If I want to target MySql database called: "FIware_Test" in my example.

And then I want to store all the data regardless of entetyID in a single table called Sensors_Data. In other words I dont want a new table for each entetyID there is, I want all of it in one table.

Comment: Just to know how to modify my previous answer to be more clear... should I understand you know and understand what a HTTP header is?

Comment: Ok, I have modified my answer assuming you know the topic ;) However, there is a lot of information about it, in the case you it (for example: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039)

Comment: Ok and I do this only in the updateContext?  I dont have to do it in the subscribeContext again?

Comment: I just tested and the Database part doesnt work, the table part does work however. Am I supposed to previously create the db or not? because I tried both...
I will link my update context in the question

Comment: Remember what we were talking the other day: if using the row mode of Cygnus, the databases and tables are automatically created by Cygnus. If not working, it is due to some configuration error (and we'll catch it ;))

Comment: I am using the row mode, and as you can see in the curl command I marked database name as 'Fiware-Service: FiwareDatabase', and it still doesnt create FiwareDatabase, it uses the default one 'def_serv'. It does however create two tables  allsensors_tv1_television  and  allsensors_tv2_television because I put 'Fiware-ServicePath: /AllSensors'.