# How do I change the default behaviour to store the information for each entity in a different table

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion, fiware-cygnus

**I want to configure Orion and Cygnus to store all data in a single table.**

I know that I should configure the names of databe and table based in HTTP headers like so:

```
dbName=<fiware-service-header>
tableName=<fiware-servicePath-header>_<entityId>_<entityType>
```

I was told [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29816214/how-i-specify-the-fiware-service-and-fiware-servicepath-fields-at-orion-that-set/29818532?noredirect=1#comment47771846_29818532) to ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Cygnus uses the notified `fiware-service` and `fiware-servicePath` headers to compose the names of the different backend elements. Specifically:

- MySQL

  - databases are called as `<fiware-service>`
  - table names are called as `<fiware-servicePath>_<destination>`
- HDFS

  - HDFS paths are created as `/user/<your_user>/<fiware-service>/<fiware-servicePath>/<destination>/<destination>.txt`
- CKAN

  - organizations are called as `<fiware-service>`
  - packages/datasets are called as `<fiware-servicePath>`
  - resources are called as `<destination>`

By default, `<destination>` is equals to `<entityId>_<entityType>`. This may lead, as described in the question, to the creation of a MySQL table/HDFS folder/CKAN resource per each notified entity.

Such a default destination generation may be changed by using an advanced feature of Cygnus, the pattern-based grouping; as the name suggests, the feature is based on finding (configured) patterns in the data, in order to group the context data showing the pattern. This feature allows, for instance, all the entities of a certain type are stored within a single MySQL table; or certain entities starting by a prefix are stored together in a HDFS file.

In order to activate this feature, edit the `/usr/cygnus/conf/matching_table.conf` file and add as many matching rules as you need; matching rules syntax is described [here](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-cygnus/blob/master/flume/doc/design/interceptors.md#destinationextractor-interceptor). Basically, the rules say "once the pattern-based matching is confirmed, use this new `<destination>` and this new `<fiware-servicePath>`":

```
<rule_id>|<list_of_fields_to_be_compared>|<regular_expresion>|<new_destination>|<new_fiware-servicePath>
```

Thus, a "store all the data in a MySQL table called 'my_unique_table'" rule would look like:

```
<any_unique_number>|<entityId>|.*|unique_table|my_
```

or:

```
<any_unique_number>|<entityId>|.*|_table|my_unique
```

Both rules are valid since MySQL table names are created, as already said, by concatenating `<fiware-servicePath>` and `<destination>`; in this case table name is equals to "my_"+_+"unique_table" or "my_unique"+"_table".

Comment: can you please write an example of what I should add as rules if I want entity Room1 and Room2 entered in table Rooms?

Comment: 1|entityType|Room|s|Room

Comment: Im sorry I still dont get the logic :( 
so if I have entity type Televeison and entityID TV1 and TV2

would i then add rule 2 as:

`2|entityType|Television|TV`